# Why is MySQL adding unnecessary padding to the end of query results?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm querying data from a MySQL DB but padding is appended to the end of it, past the total length of the field.

This is running in Node.js using the [mysql/xdevapi package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi) and querying MySQL Server 8.0.16 community.  The column being selected is defined as `accessKey CHAR(6)`. 
  Looking at the data through MySQL Workbench the padding is not present, which leads me to think this is an issues somewhere in the xdevapi package.

The query I'm using is:

```sql
SELECT accessKey, date FROM datasets WHERE authString = '<string we're searching by>';
```

The actual JS used for this query is:

```
let query = database.getTable('datasets').select('accessKey','date').where('authString = :auth').bind('auth', authString);
await query.execute(row =>
    {
        if (!Array.isArray(data)) data = [];
        let cDate = new Date(row[1]);
        console.log(row[0]);
        data.push([
            row[0].slice(0, 6),    //Manually trim padding
            cDate.toDateString()
            ]);
    });
```

The `console.log()` prints the following to the console:

```
1af55d000000000000
1d4da5000000000000
48e027000000000000
2a148d000000000000
255d4c000000000000
```

The values are correct, just with extra 0's appended.  The expected result is just the first 6 characters.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying Raymond, I'm not storing any documents in this database, and I'm not running NoSQL.

Comment: i readed [X DevAPI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/) in the question which normally general is used with Collections/Documents (NoSQL) so i assumed you used NoSQL feature of MysQl 8.. it seams that Node.js package also supports normal plain SQL queries..  Never mind mine first comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things happening here.

The first is that you are using a fixed-length column datatype `CHAR(n)`, which as specified by the [X Protocol](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/plugin/x/protocol/mysqlx_resultset.proto#L312), will require additional padding when the length of the result set value is less than the fixed-length (in bytes) defined for the column datatype.

The second is that the padding character might not be correct in your case (if you are using the `utf8mb4` charset), it should have been a `' '` and not `0x00`, and that is a bug.

Another thing is that the `utf8mb4` charset defines 4 bytes per character, which means the real field length in terms of bytes would be 24 bytes and the expected output in your case would be:

```
'1af55d                  ' 
'1d4da5                  '
'48e027                  '
'2a148d                  '
'255d4c                  '
```

This might be somewhat weird, and there's a chance it can change in the future. However, at least in this case you would be able to use `.trim()` and don't care about the value length. Until it changes, or the bug is fixed, you can always use `VARCHAR` to prevent that from happening.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!  Using a `VARCHAR` instead fixed the issue.  As for the inconsistent padding, I also discovered that the fields will be padded with zeros unless you append strings to the value stored - i.e. `.values("" + accessKey + "")` has the correct padding.  Hopefully that'll help you track down the bug!